# IIdentity and IPrincipal Interfaces

Tags: c#, security

I've always seen the `IPrincipal` and `IIdentity` interfaces separately, but I haven't seen any compelling reason for it, so I have my own interface that combines the two:

```
public interface IUser : System.Security.Principal.IIdentity, System.Security.Principal.IPrincipal {
    string Role { get; set; }
}
```

Then I implement the interface as:

```
public class User : IUser {
    public string Role { get; set; }

    public System.Security.Principal.IIdentity Identity {
        get { return this; }
    }

    public string AuthenticationType {
        get { throw new System.NotImplementedException(); }
    }

    public bool IsAuthenticated {
        get { throw new System.NotImplementedException(); }
    }

    public string Name {
        get { throw new System.NotImplementedException(); }
    }

    public bool IsInRole(string role) {
        throw new System.NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Does this [smell](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_smell)?  Do I have a security issue here?

Comment: I doubt this is `code review`. It looks more like a design question.

Comment: @Snowbear: Why wouldn't it be? Design is often discussed here anyhow.

Comment: Well... it's code that I wanted reviewed... I figured Code Review was the perfect place.  :]

Comment: I mean that the only thing worth discussing I see here is `IUser: IPrincipal, IIdentity` (we can also review `NotImplementedException` throwing - I prefer `NotSupportedException` - but I doubt this is what you want to discuss). And the question `should I implement both interfaces in one place?` should not be here.

Comment: Specific code design is on-topic here. Abstract is not.

Comment: My production code doesn't throw the exceptions.  I just created a quick example to the makeup of the class.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

While there are circumstances where you need to decouple the Principal from the Identity, in many applications this is not the case, and the distinction will only complicate the code.  The way security is best handled in an application depends very much on the individual needs of the particular app.

Martin Fowler's article [Dealing with Roles](http://martinfowler.com/apsupp/roles.pdf) provides an in depth analysis on to the different patterns that can be used to implement role-based security, and the indications of necessity for each pattern.

In general, you can't make an assumption that a solution that separates the principal from the identity is the optimal solution for all applications.  I have encountered many scenarios where it was unnecessary and added nothing but additional classes.  In that case, it is better to merge the two interfaces.

Furthermore, these are **interfaces** not **classes**.  An **interface denotes a "has a"** relationship between the instance and the definition, where as a **class denotes an "is a"** relationship.  An instance of a `User` in the OP's example is an object that has both an Identity and a Principal (Security Context).  You can always break things down to further levels of complexity, but **if the application functionality doesn't indicate a reasonable need to separate the class, then Why would you do it?**

Comment: _"interface denotes a "has a" relationship"_? Here I was thinking interfaces define a 'can/is' relationship, and composition defines a 'has a' relationship. I do agree with your other points, hence my reply in a comment on my answer.

Comment: @Steven, a "can do" relationship, is applicable to an interface.  I suppose that a class that implements and interface has a "has a" relationship to the interface's properties and a "can do" relationship to the interface's methods.  Composition seems to me like part of the implementation as opposed to part of the definition.  Check out the answer in this SO post  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/56867/interface-vs-base-class

Comment: @smartcaveman: I'm talking about [Class Diagram](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Class_diagram) definitions here ... Stating that _"interfaces denotes 'has a'"_ is very confusing and seems incorrect to me. Apparently interfaces should be interpreted as 'realizes'. Isn't it the other way around, composition is part of the definition as opposed to part of the implementation?

Comment: P.s.: Definition disagreements or not, the problem stated in my answer remains. In your words: An instance of `User` has both an `Identity` and a `Principal`, and `Principal` has an `Identity`. As stated in my comment on my answer, I believe only implementing `IPrincipal` is the only logical design when you want to bundle the two together.

Comment: @Steven, I think you are confusing associations and [inheritance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inheritance_in_object-oriented_programming).  In the OP's example, the User is an object that has an identity (`IIdentity`) and a security context (`IPrincipal`).  The `IPrincipal` also has an Identity as a property.  This could be implemented by composition (as in your suggestion) or by polymorphism (as in the OP's code).

Comment: @Steven, If you think there is only one logical design, I think reviewing the Fowler article I linked to would be tremendously helpful for you.

Comment: @smartcaveman: I'm not arguing the possibilities of different designs, but the design is already given no? As defined by the interfaces. By design, IPrincipal has an IIdentity. Implementing both is just confusing IMHO, and not following the given design.

Comment: @Steven, (1) The class design is not already made.  The interface design is.  If they were meant to always be separate classes, then they would be abstract classes instead of interfaces.  (2) By design, `IPrincipal` has an `IIdentity` property.  That does not necessarily mean that the Principal is different than the Identity.  There is nothing wrong with an `IPrincipal` implementation that also implements `IIdentity`, and the implementation of `IIdentity IPrincipal.Identity{get{return this;}}`.

Comment: Also, notice how there is no setter on the `IPrincipal` interface?  This means that the `IPrincipal` implementation is responsible for determining how the `IIdentity` object is resolved.  If there were a setter, then you would have a solid case for always favoring composition over polymorphism....but there isn't....  so, you don't.

Answer (score 2):

These interfaces are meant to [work with the user’s identity information](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ftx85f8x.aspx).

- [`IIdentity`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.principal.iidentity.aspx): An identity object represents the user on whose behalf the code is running.
- [`IPrincipal`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.principal.iprincipal.aspx): A principal object represents the security context of the user on whose behalf the code is running, including that user's identity (`IIdentity`) and any roles to which they belong.

Just from looking at the documentation, your implementation looks weird. You are permanently linking the identity of a user to a fixed role. As far as I understand it, [a user might operate on different roles at different times](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dc8ztsad.aspx). This provides for better encapsulation. The main 'design' problem I see is your identity now contains an identity, which contains an identity, with inside, ... an identity, and there ... you get the point.

Futhermore, perhaps the default implementations of `IIdentity` and `IPrincipal` can already help you? Take a look at the [generic implementations](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.principal.aspx).

Comment: The stub code above doesn't show it, but my implementation does support a user being in multiple roles;  `Roles` is a better name for the property.  

In my implementation, I have a `User` class that is tied directly to the database.  I have a struct named `UserInfo` that implements the `IUser` interface and is constructed from the `User` object.  The `UserInfo` is stored in the session (this is a web app), and is assigned to `Request.User` during `Request.BeginRequest`.

I guess I don't understand why I wouldn't want a class to represent both the user and their current security context.

Comment: @Andy: Fair, but isn't that exactly what `IPrincipal` does, and why IPrincipal contains an `IIdentity`?

Comment: @Andy: If you really do want it in one class, I suggest only implementing IPrincipal, and initializing the identity in your class instead of passing it as a parameter.

Comment: As @Steven Jeuris notes, IPrincipal has a IIdentity. There might be a set of cases where something might both 'is a' and 'has a' IIdentity (duality of identities, perhaps for handling delegation or something of similar fashion and even then I might handle that scenario a bit differently), but I don't think that structure and behavior is what you are aiming for here.